# Javascript remove bounds on zoom out

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have made a simple map in Leaflet. When a user selects a region from a drop down list, a rectangle boxes using the bound method appears.  What i want to do when the zoom on the map is less the 10 i want the rectangle of that area to be removed. Here is some code to help you understand

This created the the rectangle and zooms to area

```
function bound(bounds) {
var bounds;

L.rectangle(bounds, { weight: 1.0, color: "blue" }).addTo(map);
// zoom the map to the rectangle bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
```

This is a fucntion adds co-ordinates to the bounds function

```
  function Galway() {
var bounds = [[52.9959, -10.3357], [53.4431, -8.8602]];
// create an orange rectangle
bound(bounds);
 }
```

On zoom out less than 10 i want to the bounds to disappear

Answer (score 0):

Use an eventlistener on your map:

```
  map.on('zoomend', function() {
        if (map.getZoom() < 10){
             // remove bounds here, set default bounds or whatever you need to do
          }
        });
```